# Why does it need left property to be centered?

Tags: css

I just go to this site: http://www.domdesignonline.de/.

Take a look at `div#siteend`, I don't understand why to be centered, it needs the `left` property. I'm CSS beginner.

Thanks first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div#siteend` has a width of `100%` and it is contained in a `div` that is less than `100%` wide.

This means that if it doesn't have `left:0;` then the left side of the bounding box will be on the inner-leftside of the parent item (`div#wrap`).

You could also leave out the `left:0;` and make the width of `div#siteend` the same as `div#wrap` and you would achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for clear answer, I will take the second method, it's clearer and easier to understand.
But is #siteend is inside of #wrap so it's gonna have the same width ?

Comment: When you use `position:fixed;`, `div#siteend` does not automatically have the same width as its parent (`div#wrap`) as it normally does. This means you need to manually make the width the same in both.

Answer (score 1):

its fixed div to the end of the page .
the fixed div still visible at a definite point whatever you scroll the page they did it with
**left:0;bottom:0;**
and its text is cetered with **text-align:center;**

Comment: honestly I don't quite understand what you mean ? if you only need text-align center, it should be centered but it's not. I don't talk about fixed position

Comment: he asked "I don't understand why to be centered, it needs the left property". and i wanted to say that the left property isn't the key for centering but left is for fixing position